# YouTube PlayListitemInsert code not working API

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have code that executes a youtube upload that's working fine, when it's done, it then attempts to move the video to a specific playlist.

For testing, I have hardcoded the playlist (it's correct and re-verified) and the videoid (it does exist in my channel) into the code.

I cannot get the video to to the playlist I specify and get the output below from the NSlog query1, but no errors.

Query1: GTLQueryYouTube 0x1700b0860: {method:youtube.playlistItems.insert params:(part) bodyObject:GTLYouTubePlaylistItem}

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
// Enter PlaylistItem Code
GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistitem = [[GTLYouTubePlaylistItem alloc] init];
GTLYouTubePlaylistItemSnippet *playlistitemSnippet = [[GTLYouTubePlaylistItemSnippet alloc] init];

playlistitemSnippet.playlistId = @"PL4YcQc6s41BjKOoAPAQ_B-KNC2JBB3gl2";
playlistitemSnippet.resourceId.kind = @"youtube#video";
playlistitemSnippet.resourceId.videoId = @"4frmxoGMOcQ";

GTLQueryYouTube *query1 = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsInsertWithObject:playlistitem part:@"snippet"];


UIAlertView *waitIndicator1 = [Utils showWaitIndicator:@"Moving Video to Playlist"];

NSLog(@"Query1: %@", query1);

[service executeQuery:query1
           completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                               GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *resource, NSError *error) {
               [waitIndicator1 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up scrapping this and used the playlist auto add feature in youtube.  Way easier.